# asp.net cms that allow customers to personalize pages

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, content-management-system

I look for CMS (asp.net or asp.net mvc) that allow customers to personalize layout of widgets on a page, for example, like iGoogle or in a different way. It must be easy for customers. Are there anything?

Comment: I wouldn't consider iGoogle a CMS.  It sounds like you want users (customers) to have the ability to drag and drop, rearrange the order of pieces of content, etc?  If that's the case, try searching on drag and drop in .NET for a starting point.

Comment: You could create your own, basing it on ASP.NET web parts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

take a look to [www.dotnetnuke.com](http://www.dotnetnuke.com/)

Answer (score 1):

Telligent Community Server
http://telligent.com/

Also check out http://www.sitefinity.com/ by Telerik.

You can also make your own CMS pretty easily.  In ASP.NET, the trick of it is that you want to have a macro you can find for your widget in your content.  For the SendToPerson.com CMS, I made it so you can put a macro like [WIDGET-BLOG] in your text.  The CMS will detect that using a RegEx, and then look in my /widgets/ folder for /blog.ascx.  It will load the control dynamically by calling LoadControl("/widgets/blog.ascx"), and then it will call the Render function on that control, and then replace the macro in the text with the control output - voila!

A CMS is pretty much just put a pretty WYSIWIG editor like Telerik's on a page, save the value to a database, and then serve that content when the page is requested.